# Laravel valet with beanstalkd

Tags: php, laravel, beanstalkd, forge, laravel-valet

I am trying to use Beanstalkd in Laravel valet but it wont work.

I've installed Beanstalkd using brew and I start it up by typing beanstalkd.

The only problem is that my queues never start. And queue:listen wont return anything and I don't see any error in my logs. But if I try my application on laravel forge the queues works fine.

Are there any other settings I have to fix when running Beanstalkd with Valet?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not installed pda/pheanstalk package, you should install it. It is the client for the beanstalkd workqueue